# Sitecore:Remove Files from existing package in Sitecore

Tags: package, sitecore

Can any one suggest me on how to remove files from a existing sitecore package(**Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove rev. 130924**
 ) so that it contains only sitecore items and no sitecore files(dll or config files or xml controls that we see in sitecore modules folder).

And we will be deploying the files manually after installing this new package .

Thanks,
Suhas

Comment: You really should have your custom changes checked-in your source control, that way you can install the package and then just deploy your customizations back over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a zip archive. Inside it you will find another zip; "package.zip". Inside that package file, you will find a root folder named "files". Remove that folder, and zip the whole think back up again.

Should be all you need.

Documentation here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Installing%20Modules%20and%20Packages.aspx

Comment: Hi Mark,I tried doing this but once we remove the files folder from the package and zip it and try to install..\The package gets corrupted and none of the items gets installed.

Comment: Leave the files folder in the package as an empty folder. That should work

Comment: @Martijin:In the package,Properties folder also contains files folder.Should i empty that as well.

Comment: According to Sitecore (http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Installing%20Modules%20and%20Packages.aspx), you need to remove the /files folder entirely, not just the contents of it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MarkCassidy:Removing the files folder entirely corrupted the package and it did not get installed properly.However emptying the files folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files folder direct from Zip file.